# What am I missing out on by only running .Net 2.0 vs 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

It seems that 3.5 was a big leap from 2.0.  My workplace is still stuck on 2.0.  What kind of fun am I missing out on by not being able to upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234/what-net-framework-version-should-i-ship-with-2-3-3-5

Comment: That's not an exact duplicate. It's similar, but it is not the same and the answers do not provide the same information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A few things off the top of my head:

- Extension methods.
- lambda expressions
- better json serialization support
- linq
- WCF
- WPF
- WF
- collection initializers
- object intializers
- anonymous types

We're still on 2.0 here, as well.

Comment: Technically, not entirely true. Extension methods just need C#3.0 and can easily be used in .NET 2.0, same goes for collection and object initializers and anonymous types.

Comment: You can't use them "out of the box".

Comment: Extension methods do require the declaration of an attribute type, but the others do not. Just C#3.0 targetted at .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

You miss, anonymous variable, lambda operator, LINQ (very powerfull), extension-method (very powerfull to) and a lot of features

[Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx)

Comment: 2.0 supports anonymous functions

Answer (score 2):

**LINQ**

I know it's already been said several times, but in my opinion LINQ (optionally using lambda syntax to make things clearer) has been a game changer - entire modules of code can sometimes be rolled into a single coherent LINQ statement, and the result isn't just easier to write, it's easier to read and maintain because you aren't dealing with mountains of boiler plate code - it's purified, near 100% business logic.

Answer (score 1):

- Anything having to do with LINQ
- lambda
  expressions.
- Extension methods

Comment: plus WCF, WPF, WF and a lot more!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of development you do (windows forms vs. asp.net). Here are some points:

- If you want to use LINQ
- Ajax is integrated in the framework
- webparts drag and drop works in firefox browser
- Also if you want to use other things like micorsoft chart, workflow foundation etc.

There are many other things. Just google on it and you will find lots of links.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 3 is targeted at .NET 3.5.
You can make apps similar to AIR with it so you can tear an app off of the web page and make it a desktop app.  My customers love the silverlight graphs and gauges even when the rest of the app is in regular Ajax ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The two biggest things you're missing out on is some libraries.  Off the top of my head these are WCF, WPF, ASP.NET MVC.  ICBW.

If you need to stay on the .Net 2.0 framework, but can use VS 2008, then you do not miss out on LINQ ([LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx)), compile time inference, lambdas which is the real squishy chewy goodness of .Net 3.5.

The extra libraries in .Net 3.5 are worth it, and in my experience it has been a painless upgrade.  Remember that .Net 3.5 still [compiles to .Net 2.0 CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_3.5).

**Update** The advantage of targetting the .Net 2.0 is more users have .Net 2.0 on their machines than 3.5 SP1.  That means they don't have to do a massive download.

Answer (score 0):

Click Once deployment no longer requires IE... Yeah!